# log4net filtering by <logger> not working

Tags: c#, nhibernate, log4net, castle, log4net-filter

I would like to filter out certain log entries. In my config file I've tried adding the following to my appender with no luck:

```
<logger name="NHibernate">
      <level value="ERROR" />
</logger>
<logger name="NHibernate.SQL">
      <level value="ERROR" />
</logger>
<logger name="Castle">
      <level value="ERROR" />
</logger>
<filter type="log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter">
      <loggerToMatch value="/*repeat for all the above*/" />
      <acceptOnMatch value="false" />
</filter>
```

Here's the whole file, where the two `<logger/>` sections are is where I tried putting the rest of my filter attempts as well. Only concerned about the RollingFileAppender right now.

```
<log4net>
  <appender name="Console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <!-- Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number -->
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="C:\log\auto.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <maximumFileSize value="1000KB" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <logger name="NHibernate" additivity="false">
      <level value="OFF" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="NHibernate.SQL" additivity="false">
      <level value="OFF" />
    </logger>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <footer value ="&#13;&#10;"/>
      <conversionPattern value="%date %level - %message%newline%exception" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

Comment: Can you show your complete config? And do you have `ShowSql` turned on in NHibernate?

Comment: I'm taking over someone else's code here, but I'm pretty sure Castle takes care of the NHibernate configuration. We set basic connection properties but that's about it. Point being, there's no explicit call to ShowSql in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the logger configuration outside the appenders: loggers reference which appenders to use, but are not part of the appender configuration. Also you should remove the `additivity=false` as that's redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Womp, I don't know how log4net works.

All those `<logger/>` tags go right after the opening `<log4net>` tag like so

```
<log4net>

    <logger name="NHibernate" >
      <level value="ERROR" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="NHibernate.SQL">
      <level value="ERROR" />
    </logger>
...
```